# Why does animating css translate cause flicker in webkit on a black background?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations, css-transforms

As you can see from the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9t6q/) this animation flickers in webkit. It doesn't seem to matter if the animation is infinite or not. How can this be fixed? I have tried everything for hours. All the standard tricks don't seem to work on this example. Thanks for your time.

here is the code:

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
}

#box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    position:absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    -webkit-animation: box 20s linear infinite normal;
}

@-webkit-keyframes box {
    0% {-webkit-transform: translate(0,100px);}
    50% {-webkit-transform: translate(100px,0);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translate(0,100px);}
}
```

EDIT: RCorrie was right, going into the color settings of my monitor and tweaking them solved the problem!

Comment: What flickers? Moves nicely for me...

Comment: and if you mean by lagging, than forget it, it uses your hardware resources, better the config, better the animation, go for jquery instead

Comment: Have you been playing in `about:flags`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is more of an issue of how your browser or screen displays renders the image. It happens to come off more accentuated because of the high contrast colors you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thereason this happens is because the element is rendered at half pixel offset, to instead of having 1 pixel of 100% opacity, it'll be spread over 2 pixels both 50% opacity. It rapidly switches between 100% and 2x50% as it moves along, so that is what makes it flicker.

You could fix it by either making the line thicker, or speeding up your animation (the former being more effective at fixing it)

Comment: That's correct. You can see this behavior better by slowing down the animation. You will see that the line becomes 2px-wide and darker: http://jsfiddle.net/S9t6q/2/